# Displaying very many objects - javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm into making games with javascript and HTML5. In my previous games when I needed like 5 squares that moved around I'd do it like this.

```
var square0 = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  side: 10,
  velX: 5,
  velY: 5
}
var square1 = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  side: 10,
  velX: 5,
  velY: 5
}
.
.
.
var squares = [square0, square1, ... ];
```

And then put it all in a for-loop to do stuff with it. However I learned the hard way that this becomes very inefficent if you want very many objects. How should I do this if I wanted to use like 100 squares? Any ideas? Please don't use any JQuery.

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) squares.push({ x: 0, y:0, side:10, velX: 5, velY: 5});
?

Comment: The javascript part will take up a fraction of the time needed to render in HTML. Isn't your problem more related with that? If that is the case, what code you have to render?

Answer (score 0):

Computers are pretty good at repeating things. So you could create a `for` loop, in this case, to generate the array of squares. Either all the same, or you could even use `Math.random()` to change some of the parameters each time!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a quick way of generating a bunch of objects and put them in an array, you could create a function for generating them then call that function in a `for` loop.

```
function createSquare(x, y, side, velX, velY) {
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    side: side,
    velX: velX,
    velY: velY
  };
}

var squares = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  // You could generate different values here as needed
  var square = createSquare(0, 0, 10, 5, 5);
  squares.push(square);
}
```

This also sounds like a perfect opportunity for a constructor.

```
function Square(x, y, side, velX, velY) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.side = side;
  this.velX = velX;
  this.velY = velY;
}

var squares = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  squares.push(new Square(0, 0, 10, 5, 5));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!
I think this works best for my purposes, thanks to djechlin.

```
var squares = [];


for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) squares.push({ x: 20 * i  , y:100, side:10, velX: 5, velY: 5});

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
  ctx.fillRect(squares[i].x, squares[i].y, squares[i].side, squares[i].side);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create constructor function for square with options which you can override. Than you can modify your squares if you want. Check example below

```js
var squares = [];

//constructor 
function Square(setting) {
  var defaultSetting = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    side: 10,
    velX: 5,
    velY: 5
  }
  var options = setting || defaultSetting;

  this.x = options.x;
  this.y = options.y;
  this.side = options.side;
  this.velX = options.velX;
  this.velY = options.velY;

  //this function even can push your new square to squares array immediately (in constructor functions).
  squares.push(this);
}


new Square({
  x: 10,
  y: 0,
  side: 7,
  velX: 5,
  velY: 5
}); //create new exemplar 

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  new Square({
    x: 10,
    y: 0,
    side: 7,
    velX: 5,
    velY: 5
  });
  //generate 100 exemplars
}
```